# Php image upload and naming failure

Tags: php, file-upload

I have a small form to add categories. My table fields are the following:

**Name** *Required*

**Description** *Not Required*

**Photo** *Not Required*

It will create a category with all the information, it will even insert the image name in the database.

The problem I am having is it will not move the image to the uploads folder.
Also it will rename the image as follows: If image name is *avatar.jpg* it will rename it *85789avatar.jpg* in the database field.

I need it to rename the image as follows *O1CCJDSXBOM2.jpg*.

and the last issue is the image is not required and if you leave it blank it still puts 89439 numbers in the database field.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

         $Name = $_POST['name'];
         $Description = $_POST['description']; 

         if (empty($Name)) {
             $errors[] = "Name Required.";
         }
         if (!empty($errors)) {
             echo validation_errors($errors[0]);

         } else {

         $file = rand(1000, 100000). $_FILES['photo']['name'];
         $file_loc = $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];
         $file_size = $_FILES['photo']['size'];
         $folder = "uploads/";

         if (($file_size > 2097152)) {         

             echo validation_errors("Your avatar exceeds file size");        

         } else {

        move_uploaded_file($file_loc, $folder, $file);

        $db = dbconnect();
        $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO discussion_categories(Name, Description, Photo) VALUES (?,?,?)");
        $stmt->bind_param('sss', $Name, $Description, $file);
        $stmt->execute();        
        $stmt->close(); 

        header("Location: managecategories.php");
```

Comment: "_it still puts 89439 numbers in the database field._" which database field?

Comment: the photo field

Comment: Does that mean one record with the value _89439_, or 89439 records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *it will not move the image to the uploads folder also it will rename the image as follows. if image name is avatar.jpg ti will rename it 85789avatar.jpg in the database field*

[move_uploaded_file()](http://php.net/move_uploaded_file)  takes two arguments, not three. Update this line:

```
move_uploaded_file($file_loc, $folder, $file);
```

To this (to append the filename to the folder):

```
move_uploaded_file($file_loc, $folder . $file);
```

> *the last issue is the image is not required and if you leave it blank it still puts 89439 numbers in the database field.*

Because [move_uploaded_file()](http://php.net/move_uploaded_file) returns a [boolean](http://php.net/boolean), the code could be updated to only insert a record if the file was successfully uploaded.

```
if (move_uploaded_file($file_loc, $folder . $file)) {
    $db = dbconnect();
    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO discussion_categories(Name, Description, Photo) VALUES (?,?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('sss', $Name, $Description, $file);
    $stmt->execute();        
    $stmt->close(); 
}
```

Comment: it didn't change anything

Comment: I edited as you suggested it still does not upload the file and  the last part if upload your code does not allow any of the fields to add data

Comment: Are you sure that the user php is running as has permissions to write to that upload directory?

Comment: I just tried a script downloaded and it move the image to the folder.. so permissions are good something is wrong in the code

Comment: could you check the value of `$_FILES['photo']['error']` right before calling move_uploaded_file()? see what value it has, and cross-check values on [this php.net page](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)